# Mongoose Paginate: Getting this.count is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongoose, pagination

I am trying mongoose paginate but i am getting the below error.

```
TypeError: this.count is not a function
    at Function.paginate
```

Here is my code:

```
Stock.paginate({},{page, limit} ,function(err,result){
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error occurred while fetching users.' });
        }
        const { docs, total, limit, page, pages } = result;
        // console.log(docs)
        return res.json({ stock: docs, total, limit, page, pages });
    })
```

I have added the plugin to my Stock SChema.

```
const StockSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    item: {
      type: String,
    },
    quantity: {
      type: Number,
    }
  }
);

StockSchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate)
// mongoosePaginate(StockSchema);


module.exports = mongoose.model("Stock", StockSchema);
```

Please help me in understanding where i might be going wrong.

Comment: Are you using [`mongoose-paginate-v2`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-paginate-v2)?